# How to write Regex expression to extract the content in brackets, after string and the first match?

Tags: regex

I would like to use Regular expression to extract content between brackets, after some specific string and the 1st match.

Example text:

```
**-n --command PING being applied--:
Wed May 34 7:23:18  2010
[ZZZ_6323] Command [ping] failed with error [[TEZZZGH_IUE] [[EIJERTMMMMIJE_EIEJ] gdyugedyue Service [ABC] is not available in domain [DEF]. Check the content and review diejidjei. Service [ABC] Domain [DEF] ] did not ping back. It might be due to one of the following reasons:
=> Reason1
=> Reason3
=> Reason 4: deijdije djkeoidjeio.
info=4343 day=Mon year=2010*
```

I would like to extract the string between [] but after string Service and 1st match as Service could appear again later. In this case **ABC**

Could someone help me?
I am not able to combine these three conditionals.

Thanks

Comment: Since regex engines are not all the same you should specify a language.  And shortening the test string and an example of the expected result would also be helpful.

Comment: Hello I use this language PCRE2 (PHP>=7.3).
Shortening the test string is not possible as it is how I receive the info, I detailed the requirements.
An example of expected result is already written (in bold), in this case ABC

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't care about capturing square brackets inside the `[` `]` pair, by far the easiest way to do this is to use the following simple regex:

```regex
Service (\[[^\]]*\])
```

and extract only the 1st capturing group from the result using whatever regex functionality you're using. For example, using JS, you would write

```js
string.match(/Service (\[[^\]]*\])/)[1]
```

to extract the first capturing group.

If you instead want a regex that will *only* capture the first occurrence, you can exploit the greedy nature of the `*` quantifier and change the regex to this:

```
Service (\[[^\]]*\]).*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Service \[([^\]]+)\]
```

will match `Service [anything besides brackets]` and capture `anything besides brackets` in group number 1. Since regex engines work left-to-right, the first match will be the leftmost match.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/40KKVS/1).

In PHP, you could do this (code snippet generated by [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)):

```
if (preg_match('/Service \[([^\]]+)\]/', $subject, $groups)) {
    $result = $groups[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: The definition of the group name How should I write it?
I know that it can be like this: (?<Service>) but I dont know how to combine it with this part Service \[([^\]]+)\] in a single way

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the group name How should I write it? I know that it can be like this: (?) but I dont know how to combine it with this part Service [([^]]+)] in a single way